# Could my site being viewed in iframes hurt my SEO?

Tags: iframe, seo

I have studied most of the posts concerning web page being viewed in an iframe here but I was wondering if this can hurt the SEO of the framed site! I own a niece blog, lets call it **mynieceblog.com** and I recently found out that my web content, **mynieceblog.com/mypostname.html**, is viewed in an iframe by a site acting like a blog aggregator. A toolbar exists on top (has a closing button) and the url looks like **aggregator.com/content/myposttitle.html** The visitor can view my entire site content through this iframe and has the opportunity to visit relevant posts of other aggregated blogs. Here are my questions:

a. When a user visits **mynieceblog.com/mypostname.html** who gets to see visits/impressions on his google analytics?
b. Do I get incoming links from **aggregator.com**? Could this be possible only if the user closes down the toolbar?
c. Does this hurt the ranking of **mynieceblog.com** since I both see **mynieceblog.com/mypostname.html** and **aggregator.com/content/myposttitle.html** in search engine results for some keywords?

The view of my blog content through this aggregator does not hurt my site reputation. I have read that bandwidth use is an issue too! I am more concerned about my rankings and page views.

Comment: Interesting question, but I've voted to close - this question would be more at home in the Webmasters SE site.

Comment: You're probably right... Should I close this myself and post where you suggested?

Comment: No, when enough votes have been received, a mod can transfer this directly across to the other site. If you haven't already signed up for an account there (and linked it to your profile), might be worth doing so now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't harm you and probably gives you some credit. You found it yourself so it's getting traffic.

Your own Google Analytics code will be run so you will see the visitors. You can actually tell who is framing your website via the Hostname parameter in Google Analytics. Hostname seems to get set to the domain shown in the address bar.

Google does see the link but how much ranking you get from that is unknown. Somewhere between 0 and 100%! I have recently read a test where someone believed some framed content was indexed.

It cannot hurt your ranking. Worst case is that it ranks higher for a keyword so Google presents their page for you instead of yours directly.

If you're really worried about it then you could implement some JavaScript code to make your page break out of the frame. Something like this:

if (top.location != location) {
    top.location.href = document.location.href;
}

Comment: Thanks for your reply, especially the analytics info, it helped a lot! I believe that the aggregator appearing higher than me, the content creator, is not so good... I will consider the javascript code.

Comment: I checked the Hostname parameter in Google Analytics and I cannot see the domain aggregator.com, how about that? I used the old version of the analytics environment, I couldn't find my way through the new one...

Comment: I'm using the new one. I go to Content->Site Content->Pages. Add Hostname as the secondary dimension then filter out my own domain. I see a bunch of traffic from Googles translate website which frames your website in translation.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If your viewer views your website through aggregator.com then surely i wont help you for SEO. For good SEO viewers needs to visit your site directly from aggregator.com

Comment: Thanks for answering but could you be more specific on this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a question of hurting your site reputation - it won't; however, will it benefit your site? I'm unsure, but if you get any benefit, I imagine it would be less than if your site was access directly.

As [this article](http://www.straightupsearch.com/search-marketing/best-practices/seo_iframes_a_g/) suggests, the SEs may be able to spider your content through the aggregator, but the aggregator won't gain from your content (framed content is rightly considered to be outside the site), and given the dynamic architecture of many aggregators, you may also not gain much/anything.

I would imagine that the you could consider exposure of your site through an aggregator could be considered an in-bound link, but it is unclear whether SEs would agree.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I can understand that the framed content is not indexed but what if the aggregator names the content like: **aggregator.com/content/myposttitle-keyword1-keyword2.html**?

Comment: At some point in the code, there will be a link to your site... which web-servers, and thus spiders also, will have to follow in order to render the content.